# ¿Como hacer un jtable autoincrementable al momento de pegarle informacion?

Tags: java

```
for (int i = 0; i < jTable2.getRowCount(); i++) {
             indiceUltimaFila = jTable2.getRowCount() - 1;
              valor = jTable2.getValueAt(indiceUltimaFila, 0);
            try {

                PreparedStatement pst2 = cn.prepareStatement("Select top(1) * from Pick_Material where ruta ='bentel' order by folio desc");
                ResultSet rs = pst2.executeQuery();

                while (rs.next()) {
                    id = rs.getInt(1) + 1;
                    //txt_folioII.setText(rs.getString("Folio"));

                    //System.out.println("Registro  encontrado: " + rs.getText());
                    System.out.println("Registro  encontrado : " + id);
                }

            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                System.err.println("Error--Error--Error" + ex);
            }

            try {

                PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement("Insert into Pick_Material (Folio,ruta,nparte,area,areahsap,cantidad,Fk_Estado,Fecha,fk_manifiesto,serie,Fk_EstadoHsap,NumSmart,orden)"
                        + "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

                pst.setInt(1, id);
                pst.setString(2, "BENTEL");
                pst.setString(3, (String) jTable2.getValueAt(i, 0).toString().trim());
                pst.setString(4, (String) jTable2.getValueAt(i, 1).toString().trim());
                pst.setString(5, "08LH");
                pst.setString(6, (String) jTable2.getValueAt(i, 2).toString().trim());
                pst.setInt(7, 1);
                pst.setString(8, ((JTextField) jDate_Fecha.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
                pst.setInt(9, id2);
                pst.setInt(10, 1);
                pst.setInt(11, 3);
                pst.setInt(12, 1);
                pst.setInt(13, 1);

                pst.executeUpdate();
                System.out.println("Datos Guardados correctamenteeeeeeee");

            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                System.out.println("que paso" + ex);

            }


    }                                               
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡Los datos han sido guardados con éxito!", "Pedido Benteler", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        dispose();

    }
```

Comment: ¿Qué quieres que sea autoincrementable? Si no explicas el código y problema que tienes, es complicado poder ayudarte.

Comment: Lo que deseo hacer es que al momento de pegar contenido dentro de mi tabla, la tabla se ajuste a los renglones e insertarlos a una base de datos